# php include_once not working for only one file

Tags: php, include

I have two folders `Provider` and `Library` in the same directory. `Provider` includes two php files `ActiveRequests.php` and `PendingRequests.php`. `Library` contains another folder `Multilingual` which includes `Pagefactory.php` and `languageSession.php`

```
- Provider
  - ActiveRequests.php
  - PendingRequests.php
- Library
  - Multilingual
    - Pagefactory.php
    - languageSession.php
```

I'm including `PageFactory.php` in `ActiveRequests.php` like

```
      include_once __DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php'
```

and it is working fine.

But when I'm trying to include `PageFactory.php` in `PendingRequests.php` in the same way like

```
       include_once __DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php'
```

it is not working.

when I tried to include the `languageSession.php` in `Pendingrequests.php` like

```
       include_once __DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/languageSession.php'
```

it is working fine.

Can any one help me? What could be the problem with the `PageFactory.php` path?

I've also tried with `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` but it did not work.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make any typo's?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? i.e. what symptoms/errors do you see? What do you see if you use require_once() rather than include_once()?

Answer (score 1):

I've just fix a same problem,  the point is if you include `PageFactory.php` in `PendingRequests.php` you have to change every file that `PageFactory.php` refers base on `PendingRequests.php` path. I fixed my problem with this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the path as

```
echo __DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php';
```

In this way, you can check if the path to the file is correct!

Or use, `var_dump` to check the path!

To The people downvoting my answer: Printing the path is for debugging!

Or you can check the path as :

```
var_dump(file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php'));
```

`__DIR__` is the path to the parent directory. It gives path of `Provider` when used from `PendingRequests.php`.

I think the problem is you have used `../`.Try removing it!

For example, 
`__DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php'` is identical to

`path/to/Provider/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php`

So the final answer is to remove "../" and it becomes:

`__DIR__ . '/library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php'`

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that you include the file with the following:

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/../library/Multilingual/PageFactory.php'
```

While the file is called `Pagefactory.php`.

On non-Windows systems, this will make a difference. Ensure that the capitalisation is correct.

This may just be a typo in your question (the amount of typos in it originally would suggest it could be!) but it may be the cause of the problem.